# Cloudformation - Passing Parameters to second level stack

Tags: parameters, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, nested-stack

I'm trying to pass some parameters to nested stacks.

My current configuration is the following:

root template:

```
Parameters:
  SubnetIds:
    Description: The array of Subnet IDs assigned to the lambdas
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
  SecurityGroupIds:
    Description: The array of Security Groups Assigned to the lambda functions
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>

Resources:
 Myresource1:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Application'
    Properties:
      Location: 'resource1/template.yaml'
      Parameters:
        SubnetIds: !Join [',', !Ref SubnetIds]
        SecurityGroupIds: !Join [',', !Ref SecurityGroupIds]
```

first nested stack:

```
Parameters:
  SubnetIds:
    Description: The array of Subnet IDs assigned to the lambdas
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
  SecurityGroupIds:
    Description: The array of Security Groups Assigned to the lambda functions
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>

Resources:
  MySecondLevelResource:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Application'
    Properties:
      Location: 'app/template.yaml'
      Parameters:
        SubnetIds: !Ref SubnetIds
        SecurityGroupIds: !Ref SecurityGroupIds
```

second level nested stack:

```
Parameters:
  SubnetIds:
    Description: The array of Subnet IDs assigned to the lambdas
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
  SecurityGroupIds:
    Description: The array of Security Groups Assigned to the lambda functions
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
```

With this configuration I get an error when AWS tries to deploy the first nested stack because it is expecting a String or object of Strings.
I tried also to use the CommaDelimitedList type in the first level stack but then I still get an error in the second level.
So far no luck on that.

Has anyone experienced this situation or any ideas on how it can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have **a major mistake** in your templates:

```
SubnetIds: !Join [',', !Ref SecurityGroupIds]
```

The use of `SecurityGroupIds` will lead to failure as `SecurityGroupIds` are not `SubnetIds`, regardless of any other issues.

Also nested stacks are created using [AWS::CloudFormation::Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#aws-properties-stack-return-values) which has different syntax that what you are using. So the way you pass arguments **is correct** if you are actually using nested stacks by means of `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I fixed the yaml in the question (wrong copy&paste). Regarding the use of the Stack I don't think it changes in that case. `AWS::Serverless::Application` are deployed as nested Stack https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-application.html